# How To get dom documenet value list

Tags: list, string

```
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', action);
    req.setEndpoint(ep);
    req.setBody(msg);
    req.setTimeout(60000);

    HttpResponse res; 
    res = h.send(req);  
    Dom.Document  doc = res.getBodyDocument();

    string str=doc.toXmlString());
```

String  value stored the string data but how to store In list values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the root node:

```
Dom.XmlNode root = res.getBodyDocument().getRootElement();
```

then you can use the methods of [Dom.XmlNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) to walk around the tree. For example, the immediate child elements (list) would be:

```
Dom.XmlNode[] children = root.getChildElements();
```